# What receives a LSTM neuron?

Tags: lstm

I'm confused about input data on LSTM neurons. I know that exist almost two form to give data to a recurrent neural network.

I want to understand with a example

```
Data
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

For feeda RNN, data must be formatted with this schema:

```
(x,y,z)
    x = samples
    y = timestep
    z = features
```

But, I know three ways to input data:

**Way 1**
Shape =  (x,1,3)

```
data = [
        [[1,2,3]],
        [[2,3,4]],
        [[3,4,5]],
        [[4,5,6]],      
        ]
```

**Way 2**
Shape = (x,3,1)

```
data = [
        [[1],[2],[3]],
        [[2],[3],[4]],
        [[3],[4],[5]],
        [[4],[5],[6]],      
        ]
```

**Way 3**
Shape = (x,2,2)

```
data = [
        [[1,2],[3,4]],
        [[2,3],[4,5]],
        [[3,4],[5,6]],      
        ]
```

If input is *way 1*, I supose  `LSTM neurons = z`.

But I don't know what receive the neurons in way 2 and 3.